# Validate Model in View when the Model is a List<SomeModel>

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a asp.net core 3.0 MVC app. In this app I can List, Create, Edit and delete some objects (datarows). 
There are views for all of these operations:

- /Index.csltml (List of all items in a datagridview)
- /Create.cshtml
- /Update.cshtml
- /Delete.cshtml

All this, incl. validation works very fine. But I cant find a way to validate the items in the index.
When I edit the items with the app, the input gets validated and I cant enter invalid data.
But when the data are already invalid loaded, there is no hint when the view is shown.
Especially in the index view, I want to show some kind of a warning indicator in each affected row.

Is there a way to validate the model in a view when iterating through a list of it? Or is there a better approach for this?

```
//Index View
@model List<SomeModel>
<tbody>
@foreach (SomeModel m in Model)
{
    //... Validation here please!
}
</tbody>


public class SomeModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required()]
    public Guid ModelId;

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string ModelProperty:

    ...

    more properties

    ...

    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    }   
}

public class SomeController
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SomeModel> _models = SomeModel.GetModels();
        return View(_models);
    }
}

[HttpPost()]
[Route("Create")]
public IActionResult HttpPostCreate(SomeModel _model)
{
    // When posting data, the data arrives validated in the controller method
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool success = SomeModel.CreateSetting(_model);
        if (success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    return View("Create", _model);
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using to validate data in form before posting it to server. You can do same by calling validate method once page is loaded.

Comment: I am using plain vanilla asp.net core 3.0. The validation happens inside the pipline.

Comment: do you want client or server side validation?

Comment: As serverside as possible. I would prefer something like the ModelState in the controller, but in the view/*.cshtml.

Comment: I see what you want, here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138749/how-to-manually-validate-a-model-with-attributes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405897/validate-object-that-is-sent-from-a-collection-in-a-text-file/55405991#55405991 not your case?

Comment: @SenadMeškin, this could be the solution. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in deed very simple. [Like mentioned in this great tutorial.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138749/how-to-manually-validate-a-model-with-attributes)

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
<tbody>
    @foreach (SomeModel m in Model)
    { 
        ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(m);
        ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>(); 
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(m, vc, results, true);
    }
</tbody>
```